# How to correctly migrate old data saved with NSKeyedArchiver into new format while migrating from Objective-C to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

An older version of the app has a `NSCoding`-compliant class (lets call it `OldItem`), written in Objective C. This class has about 20 properties with different types:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger x;

// ...

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {

    if (self = [super init])  {
        _x = [coder decodeIntegerForKey:@"x"];
        // all 20 fields are decoded in the similar way
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    [self.x encodeWithCoder:coder];
    // all 20 fields encoded in the similar way
}
```

It's used in another class (lets call it `Controller`) as array:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong, nonnull) NSMutableArray<OldItem *> *items;
```

`Controller` also caches items to disk like this:

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.items];
[data writeToFile:@"myfile.txt" options:NSDataWritingFileProtectionComplete error:nil];
```

Now I need to migrate `OldItem` to Swift, while `Controller` only changes the type of item it handles:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong, nonnull) NSMutableArray<NewItem *> *items;
```

**Question is: how do I migrate an old data, saved in `myfile.txt` in previous version of the application into new version?**

- Ideally new class has a different name, e.g `NewItem`, but I'm open to keeping the old name, if it significantly simplifies the migration.
- Don't care if new version will be saving data into the same file, or reading an old file once, and moving data over to a new file.
- For this question, ignore any differences between `OldItem` and `NewItem`. Treat them as direct port.
- Clearly `NewItem` should still be `NSCoding`-compliant, and reading/writing `NewItem` into the file is not an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking around for a bit, the actual solution is:

1. Make sure `public required init?(coder: NSCoder)` in NewItem class properly unarchives all fields you want to preserve from OldItem. For instance enums, or number type conversions may require special handling, even if you didn't change fields per se.
2. Right before unarchiving, tell `NSKeyedUnarchiver` that NewItem should be used in place of OldItem, using `NSKeyedUnarchiver.setClass` method.

Example:

```
let archivedData = try Data(contentsOf: filePath)
NSKeyedUnarchiver.setClass(NewItem.self, forClassName: "OldItem")
let items = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(archivedData)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to migrate. NSCoder is a Cocoa thing, not a language thing; it works just the same whether you talk to it in Objective C or Swift. Just translate all the code line for line into Swift and you’re done. The old archived data keeps right on working, because an archive is still an archive and a coder is still a coder. **Edit** If the question is how to give your Swift class the old Objective C class’s name so that the archive can be read into it, note that Objective C `MyClass` and Swift `MyClass` have different names because of Swift name mangling; you have to say

```
@objc(MyClass) class Whatever : NSObject {
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. Doing that will just get you a `cannot decode object of class (OldClass) for key (NS.objects); the class may be defined in source code or a library that is not linked` error. See the real answer below.